# This can be run in protected mode or real-address mode, how do I change which it is running in?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32, protected-mode

Another question about my programming class, well actually a few.
To begin with the program has already been written and the code can be found below.

Question #1:

Now, in the instructions it explicitly states that the program can be done in *protected mode* or *real-address mode*. I'm fairly certain that Windows runs in protected mode and as such this means I have done the exercises in such a manner. If I wanted to, how would one change which mode the program executes in? Am I correct in saying windows operates in protected mode?

Question #2:

I have written a few comments in the assembly code below is the one stating how the first 16-bits of the register have been filled correct?

Question #3:

Lastly the instruction call for inclusion of the *Listing file* and *Map file* in the final submission, I cannot locate these files.

---

```
TITLE Subtracting Three Integers

; This program takes three integers in hexidecimal and then subtract the 2nd and 3rd from the first.

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.code
main PROC

    mov ax,0109h        ;stores integer 265 in ax(16-bit register)
    mov bx,0041h        ;stores integer 65 in bx(16-bit register)
    mov  cx,0064h       ;stores integer 100 in cx(16-bit register)

    sub ax,bx
    sub ax,cx
    call    DumpRegs

    comment !
    The dump regs returns the value of EAX=763B0064 BAX=7FFD0041 CAX=00000064
    because EAX EBX and ECX are 32-bit registers they fill the first 16-bits with
    unallocated data from other programs
    !

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-** The main difference between real and protected mode is that in real mode, any program can access any memory location, and in protected mode, programs can only access certain memory locations that are laid out for them. The issues with real mode are obvious- any program on your computer could watch your every move. As this is a huge security issue, real mode became obsolete, and now almost all modern operating systems run in protected mode.

Your program can run in either mode, as it does not access any out-of-bounds memory locations. All of the code is laid out in memory and stays within the limits. General purpose registers are not in memory, so you are safe there also.

**2-** You are correct. Watch out, though- if `ax` is signed, then the value `265` is too large for a 16-bit register.

**3-** A "map" file is a file that shows how the segments are laid out in your code. It also can show symbols and their virtual addresses. A "linker" file demonstrates command locations, values, and their relation to the individual opcodes that you put in. Both of these can be generated with your compiler.

Comment: In this case my compiler is Microsoft's Visual studio assembling for x86 using the included compiler, how do I get it to spit out such files? Also I thought that 16-bit could handle up to +/-65,535 and 8-bit was limited to +/-255, do bits store a different amount in the registers?

Comment: @Mr.Kruel About 16 bit- It can be 0 to 65,535 or -256 to 256. It cannot be -65,535 to 65,535.

Comment: @Mr.Kruel For the listing file, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx). For the map file, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2.aspx).

Comment: So when the value is signed does it take 8-bits to be recognized as signed or why does it lose so much of its capacity?

Comment: @Mr.Kruel Come to a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49655/chat-between-blue-ice-and-mr-kruel) where we can discuss this together. The comments are getting a bit messy :)

Comment: Im not reputable enough to chat in a chat room.

Comment: @Mr.Kruel Then I can explain it here. First, let's look at how bits work. A bit has two values - 1 or 0. 16 bits means that there are 2^16 possible values. With unsigned- that is, all positive values- all 16 bits are used for numeric value. This means that there is an upper bound of 2^16 (65,535) and a lower bound of 0. But when you make the signed 16-bit int have 1 sign value (1 or 0, + or -) and you make the other 15 bits numeric values, the upper bound is **+** 2^15 (256) and the lower bound is **-** 2^15 (-256). The difference between unsigned and signed is how the values are accessed.

Comment: 2^15 is 256? Surely there is some other explanation for why signed ax can only contain 513 distinct values?